# Problem with c# constructors

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-3, constructor

Using Asp.Net-MVC music store tutorial, concrete page is at :

http://www.asp.net/mvc/tutorials/mvc-music-store-part-3

```
<ul>    
    @foreach (var genre in Model)  
    {  
        <li>
            @Html.ActionLink(genre.Name,"Browse", new { genre = genre.Name })
        </li>  
    }  
</ul>
```

Variable genre is reference for Object created in Controller Class which has one property - Name, and i can't menage to understand this `new{genre=genre.Name}` instantiation-assignment. Can someone give me a link or explanation of this language feature?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That looks like [Anonymous type](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb397696.aspx).

Answer (score 5):

It is an [object initializer](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb384062.aspx), creating an [anonymous type](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb397696.aspx).

In this case, the anonymous type has a `genre` string property, initialized to the enclosing `genre.Name` property.

The naming in this code sample is a bit poor and can be confusing.

Comment: Thx man,    renamed that property of anonymous type to be location_id for now. Cool, so when it comes to anonymous types i can define them without following declaration and use them as some kind of short life helper types. Do correct me if wrong.

Comment: @streetspirit - short lived types is indeed one of the use cases for anonymous types (very useful in LINQ).